# Can JS read a local file from local web-page?

Tags: javascript, file, local, html

I'd like to use html+css+js to create an interface for setting up a simulation. The interface is used to create a visualisation of the simulation, and an output parameters file, by using several input files.

This web-page does NOT need to run on a server and is only run locally on the same machine.

I understand why a sever page is not allowed to access a client file, and that a server page may access another server file. Is it possible for a LOCAL web-page to access a local file?

It is possible to view the contents of any file using `file:///path/to/file.txt` so I presume that it is somehow possible to pull the result into a running page in the form of a string. However I'm having very little success.

If it is possible please could you detail a simple example of how the contents of a txt file could be read into a string?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's not possible, as far as I know. There are several frameworks for building desktop applications using HTML/CSS/JS. You could always try your hand at an electron-based app, for example. That lets you access files using node.js fs functions.

Comment: If you don't mind user interaction, were the user selects the files,..  Then you could just use `input type[file]` and read the data.   direct access `file://` is blocked by browsers for security reasons, although there is often flags you can set to override this.

Comment: Thanks both. @Keith I am aware of the --allow-file-access-from-files flag for chrome, I was hoping something similar would automatically be applied for locally running pages.

Answer (score 1):

`node.js` is a javascript implementation that can easily do such things because it is a process running on the machine. A web page is running in a browser which does not have access to the file system, so that would not be possible, however you could bundle your web application into an [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) application which would be able to access the `os`and file system, so while it would use html and javascript it would still require an installation.

Comment: I have toyed with node.js but ideally I'd like to avoid having to run node each time I want to use the interface. From yours and @Jacob's suggestions it looks like electron might be what I'm after. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Chrome, you can launch it with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.  Then you can do:

```
fetch('file:///path/to/file.txt')
.then(function(response) {
    // do something with it
})
```